# How to query interpolation in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Since I need to check the empty value of the time series stored in Apache IoTDB, I would like to ask is there any function for interpolation query when querying data in IoTDB? If there is this kind of function, what should I do to check all these empty fields out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache IoTDB, you can directly replace the empty fields with the value you want (previous value, linear interpolation of the previous non-null value and the next non-null value, or a certain constant), instead of query them out and then try to replace them.
To achieve this, try `FILL '(' PREVIOUS | LINEAR | constant ')'` command and choose the kind of filling value method you want.